# How to Extend Selection to whole paragraph via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, selection

I am using this code to extend selection to whole line on word document, Now I want to extend selection to whole paragraph

```
Selection.Expand wdLine
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a different WdUnit like wdParagraph:

```
Selection.Expand wdParagraph
```

See this link for an overview of the different WdUnits:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838950.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you know one of the enumerated values then you can use the `Object Explorer` to find the name of the Enumeration.  By referencing the Enumeration you'll be able to use Intellisense to determine all the valid values.

[image]