# Select code snippet in document, using the VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I want to create a macro, which will allow to select entire code blocks in the document.

This is what I currently have:

```
Sub SelectSnippet()
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Code")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

The problem is, that it selects only the next line of code, instead of snippet entirely.

Visually:

[image]

Comment: after `selection.find` ... do  `selection.expand wdUnit` ....  see this for wdUnit value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759119/how-to-extend-selection-to-whole-paragraph-via-vba#40759502

Comment: @jsotola I will try to play with it more, but currently `wdParagraphFormatting` (the unit which looks like what I need) gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the job. Please try.

```
Sub SelectSnippet()

    Dim Styl As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Boolean

    Styl = "Code"
    Set Rng = Selection.Range               ' start at the selection
    ' find the nearest different style before the selection
    With Rng
        Do While .Start > 1
            If .Style <> Styl Then Exit Do
            .Move wdCharacter, -1
        Loop
    End With

    ' look for the first occurrance of the style
    On Error Resume Next
    With Rng.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Style = Styl
        Fnd = .Execute
    End With
    If Err Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation, "Can't find """ & Styl & """"
    End If

    If Fnd Then
        ' expand the range to the end of the style
        With Rng
            Do While .End < .Document.Characters.Count
                If .Document.Range(.End, .End + 1).Style <> Styl Then Exit Do
                .MoveEnd wdCharacter, 1
            Loop
            .Select                         ' select the range
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The following code does the same job but looks at complete paragraphs only. If a part of a paragraph isn't of the same style it may or may not be included.

```
Sub NewSelectSnippet()

    Dim Styl As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim DocRng As Range
    Dim p As Integer

    Styl = "Code"
    ' expand the section to include the entire paragraph
    Set Rng = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
    If Rng.Style <> Styl Then Exit Sub

    ' expand the range to include preceding paragraphs of same style
    Set DocRng = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Rng.End)
    With DocRng.Paragraphs
        For p = .Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Item(p).Range.Style = Styl Then
                Rng.MoveStart wdParagraph, -1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next p
    End With

    ' expand the range to include following paragraphs of same style
    With ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        For p = (DocRng.Paragraphs.Count + 1) To .Count
            If .Item(p).Range.Style = Styl Then
                Rng.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next p
    End With

    Rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. It looks very complex, and that's why, I'm very appreciated for it. But it doesn't properly work - at least, in Word 2016. (I haven't tested on another versions). This macro always selects only the 1st paragraph of the snippet. [Here it is](https://i.imgur.com/TbrLWVK.png).

Comment: Yes indeed. It should be ` Do While .End < .Document.Characters.Count` of course, `<` not `>`. I have corrected this in the code above.

Comment: Word freezing for about 10 seconds after this macro launched, but it works, and after 10 seconds, the snippet is really selected :)

Comment: Try assigning `.Document.Characters.Count` to a variable and use that variable in the comparison `Do While .End < .Document.Characters.Count`. I don't really believe that will make all the difference but it should be a little faster. The code must check every character's style. Are there so many characters to check?

Comment: Yes, variable doesn't do perceptible difference. Just of curiosity, is it necessary to check every character, instead of check every paragraph? From my point of view, it should be faster and better, because for code snippets I use **paragraph** style, not **character** style. So, I have changed your code a bit according to this idea, and [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/nspkx56x/) (see the comments in code). What do you think about my alterations? Is it correct, or I must change the `Do While .End < .Document.Characters.Count` line as well?

Comment: I have added code to my answer above which would look at paragraphs only. The basic system is simpler.

Comment: Thank you. Have a great weekend!